# How to use Aiduino module to connect to computer network?

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, hardware, networking

I have 4 usb Hard Drives and I just want to connect them to computer network directly without a traditional computer. Is there an any module with 4 usb ports and one RJ45 port. The module should able to connect drives to network as NAS (Network Area Storage) or other mounting possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Arduino is completely incapable of doing such a difficult task. It's literally impossible because the processor isn't strong enough, it has no built in network capabilities that support NAS, it has no USB software built in, and so on and so on.

But you *can* use a Raspberry Pi. They are cheap for their capabilities, they do require quite some programming to get it to work but there's a huge community that has guides for everything. Best of luck :)